# How to optimize this if else block to compare date in simple React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization

I am learning React. This is a simple project fetching fake JSON data and populating the table. Over here I am trying to compare dates and check if that object's birthday is today for the current year.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Birthday extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.verifyBirthday = this.verifyBirthday.bind(this);
  }

  verifyBirthday(date) {
    let today = new Date();
    let bDate = new Date(date);
    let todayDate = today.getDate();
    let bDateDate = bDate.getDate();
    let todayMonth = today.getMonth();
    let bDateMonth = bDate.getMonth();
    let msg = "";
    if (todayMonth < bDateMonth) {
      msg = "has yet to occur";
    } else if (todayMonth > bDateMonth) {
      msg = "already happened";
    } else {
      if (todayDate < bDateDate) {
        msg = "has yet to occur";
      } else if (today > bDateDate) {
        msg = "already happenned";
      } else {
        msg = "it's today!";
      }
    }

    return msg;
  }

  render() {
    let birthdayStatus = this.verifyBirthday(this.props.date);
    //console.log(typeof birthdayStatus);
    //console.log(birthdayStatus);
    return <span> {birthdayStatus} </span>;
  }
}

export default Birthday;
```

I tried MomentJs but found to be useless in the case because the date I am receiving is in this format 
`"Tuesday, August 1, 1972 8:45 PM"`
which I have to convert into date object and then to moment and diff in Moment object doesn't exclude year. Need to compare the dates to check if the Birthday occurred for the current year.

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by optimising the if else black. What actually do you want to do?

Comment: I updated the question for all those who have answered, I need to check if the Birthday of all this object has occurred for the current year, based on the birthday present in the JSON file. Regardless of which year they are born, I need to see if they had their birthday this year.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do what you ask:

```js
function compareDateWithoutTime(dateA, dateB) {
  let date1 = new Date(dateA);
  let date2 = new Date(dateB);
  date1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  date1.setFullYear(1969); //just any year is ok
  date2.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  date2.setFullYear(1969);
  return date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
}

function isItMyBirthday(birthday) {
  let birthsDayCompare = compareDateWithoutTime(
    birthday,
    new Date()
  );
  return birthsDayCompare === 0
    ? "it's today!"
    : birthsDayCompare > 0
    ? 'already happened'
    : 'has yet to occur';
}

console.log(
  '2020-03-10 01:00:34',
  isItMyBirthday('2021-03-10 01:00:34')
);
console.log(
  '2000-03-10 01:00:34',
  isItMyBirthday('2000-03-10 01:00:34')
);
console.log(new Date(), isItMyBirthday(new Date()));
```

Comment: Assuming date1 is today then `(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())  > 0` in the past, `(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())  < 0` in the future and `(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())  === 0` is today

Comment: added additional func to make it more clear....  to your case

Comment: I update the question. I need to know if those birthdays have already happened this year. Regardless of the year, they have been born.

Comment: @user1319417 pls review my edit w/ date1.setFullYear(), overriding the year to whatever will solve the issue..

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use momentjs you can set the year of the object's birthday and use the isAfter, isBefore, isSame functions.

```
function verifyBirthday(date) {
  const newdate = moment(date).startOf('day').set('year', moment().get('year'));

  return moment().startOf('day').isAfter(newdate) ? "already happenned" : moment().isBefore(newdate) ? "has yet to occur" : "it's today!";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Luxon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/luxon) which it has a very nice [`fromFormat`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#static-method-fromFormat) method that will parse your date format using `DDDD` and the time `h:mm a` formats.

> **Token**: `DDDD`
>
> **Description**: *localized date with full month and weekday*
>
> **Example**: *Wednesday, August 6, 2014*

You can check the [`Table of Tokens`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/parsing.html#table-of-tokens) for more details.

#### React parsing and siplaying example:

```jsx
import { DateTime } from "luxon/build/node/luxon";

const Data = [{
  'name': 'Nick',
  'dob': 'Tuesday, August 1, 1972 8:45 PM'
}, {
  'name': 'George',
  'dob': 'Monday, March 10, 1980 3:24 PM'
}, {
  'name': 'Gregory',
  'dob': 'Wednesday, March 19, 1997 7:10 PM'
}, {
  'name': 'Maria',
  'dob': 'Friday, March 20, 1964 9:37 PM'
}, {
  'name': 'Liza',
  'dob': 'Thursday, March 21, 1974 9:37 PM'
}];

...

renderItem({ name, dob }) {
  const dateOfBirth = DateTime.fromFormat(dob, "DDDD h:mm a");
  const now = DateTime.local();
  const hasBirthday = dateOfBirth.month === now.month && dateOfBirth.day === now.day;

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{name}</td>
      <td>{dateOfBirth.toFormat("EEE d, MMM y")}</td>
      <td>{hasBirthday ? 'Happy Birthday!' : null}</td>
    </tr>
  );

}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <table border="1">
        <th>Name</th><th>DOB</th><th>Has Birthday</th>
        {this.state.data.map(d => this.renderItem(d))}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check this working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rdpfze